# Getting current annotation information to display in a view in xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, annotations

In my application I would like when the user clicks an annotation for for my UITextviews to show some more descriptive information about that annotation like title, latitude, and longitude. My issue is I have no idea on how to get this information after the annotations have been added to the map. Here is some of my code I am using for the MKAnnotationView which is just built into my custom view controller.

```
    MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
    {
        MKAnnotationView annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(annotationIdentifier);
        // Set current location and location of annotation
        CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation = mapView.UserLocation.Coordinate;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationLocation = annotation.Coordinate;

        // We don't want a special annotation for the user location
        if (currentLocation.Latitude == annotationLocation.Latitude && currentLocation.Longitude == annotationLocation.Longitude)
            return null;

        if (annotationView == null)
            annotationView = new MKPinAnnotationView(annotation, annotationIdentifier);
        else
            annotationView.Annotation = annotation;

        annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;
        (annotationView as MKPinAnnotationView).AnimatesDrop = false; // Set to true if you want to animate the pin dropping
        (annotationView as MKPinAnnotationView).PinColor = MKPinAnnotationColor.Red;
        annotationView.SetSelected(true, false);

        _annotationDetailButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
        _annotationDetailButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //put create segue her
            PerformSegue("ShowCollectionDetail", Self);

        };

        annotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = _annotationDetailButton;

        // Annotation icon may be specified like this, in case you want it.
        // annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("example.png"));
        return annotationView;
    }
```

Comment: Did you take a look at my answer?

Comment: I did, I am getting information about the annotations but not the one that is currently selected. I added this code to the GetViewForAnnotation method. SculptureTitle.Text = annotationView.Annotation.GetTitle(); Any suggestions on what I am still doing incorrect. It seems I am getting annotations not on the current display.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom MKAnnotation as follows:

```
public class AnnotationModel : MKAnnotation
{
    private string _title;
    private string _subtitle;

    public AnnotationModel(CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate, string title, string subtitle = "")
    {
        this.Coords = coordinate;
        _title = title;
        _subtitle = subtitle;
    }

    public override string Title { get { return _title; } }
    public override string Subtitle { get { return _subtitle; } }
    public CLLocationCoordinate2D Coords;
    public override CLLocationCoordinate2D Coordinate { get { return this.Coords; } }
}
```

Then you can use this annotation in your `GetViewForAnnotation()` method. 
For more info look at this [link](http://leiflarsen.azurewebsites.net/xamarin-tutorial-ios-mapkit-part-2/).

Comment: Basically I just want to show information on the current selected Annotation when the user clicks on it.

Comment: Hey I got it! Found out that, I just needed to call DidSelectAnnotationView on the map view. Then added my own event where I called map.selectedannotations which returned the current selected annotation then i accused the infomation with the custom class you showed me thanks!

Comment: map.DidSelectAnnotationView += (object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e) => 
{
    annoList = map.SelectedAnnotations;
    foreach (IMKAnnotation a in annoList)
    {
     SculptureTitle.Text = a.GetTitle();
    }
   };

Comment: I am happy to hear that you managed to make it work and my answer was actually helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
map.DidSelectAnnotationView += (object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e) =>
```

{
                annoList = map.SelectedAnnotations;
                foreach (IMKAnnotation a in annoList)
                {
                    SculptureTitle.Text = a.GetTitle();
                }
            };